# Regex to match and split every third occurrence of a string

Tags: regex, string, shell, ksh, aix

in a Korn Shell script I have a large amount of data in a string variable `contents` that matches the following syntax:

```
account_id_0:group_id_0:name_0
account_id_1:group_id_1:name_1
              ...
account_id_N:group_id_N:name_N
```

I want to split the string on the `:` character every third instance so I can generate three other strings `accounts`,`groups`, and `names`
that have the format:

```
accounts = account_id_0,account_id_1,...,account_id_N
groups = group_id_0,group_id_1,...,group_id_N
names = name_0,name_1,...,name_N
```

The reason I would like to store these in a string rather than an array is for portability across environments.

Am I able to achieve this using something like the `sed`, `cut`, or `awk` command?

the current regex I'm using to capture the accounts is:

```
[a-zA-Z][0-9]+(?:([a-zA-z]*[0-9]*)*)(?:([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)*)
```

But I feel there is a more efficient alternative.

I have attempted to achieve the desired output using a combination of [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312280/split-string-by-delimiter-and-get-n-th-element) and [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/396536/how-to-keep-only-every-nth-line-of-a-file) however the first one lacks the repetition I require, and the latter is for file manipulation not strings.

Comment: Can you show what values you want `accounts`, `groups` and `names` to contain?

Comment: @glennjackman for sure, I have edited the question for clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use arrays, and process the contents variable like reading lines from a file:

```
contents='account_id_0:group_id_0:name_0
account_id_1:group_id_1:name_1
...:...:...
account_id_N:group_id_N:name_N'

as=()
gs=()
ns=()
while IFS=: read -r a g n; do
    as+=("$a")
    gs+=("$g")
    ns+=("$n")
done <<< "$contents"

accounts=$(IFS=,; echo "${as[*]}")
groups=$(IFS=,; echo "${gs[*]}")
names=$(IFS=,; echo "${ns[*]}")

printf "%s\n" "$accounts" "$groups" "$names"
```

```
account_id_0,account_id_1,...,account_id_N
group_id_0,group_id_1,...,group_id_N
name_0,name_1,...,name_N
```

If you're getting the `contents` value from a file, you can skip the step of storing it in a variable and just read the file directly.

Comment: this works excellent for what I need to accomplish in an AIX environment, although this solution utilizes arrays I am accepting it as it also works in the RHEL environment I need it to. Thanks @glennjackman